# Restrict the scrolling on QChart with QBarCategoryAxis

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts, qchart

I'm trying to make the standard [Qt barchart](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-barchart-example.html) example scrollable and zoomable. I can use the scroll and zoom method of `QChart` to define a custom Chart View class that re-implement the different mouse event. However, with this technique it's possible to scroll past the range of categories.

[image: out of bounds]

It'll be a simple fix if i could get the min max value on the y axis in "chart space" but i guess since the y axis is a `QBarCategoryAxis` the only methods available return the string of the min max category.

I'm at a loss every search i come up with return results for the `QValueAxis` api.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a while. You can derive from QBarCategoryAxis to check boundaries whenever a zoom/scroll/resize event is called.

```
#include "CustomValueAxis.h"

CustomValueAxis::CustomValueAxis() : lockMin(0), lockMax(0) {}

CustomValueAxis::CustomValueAxis(int min, int max) : lockMin(min), lockMax(max) {}

void CustomValueAxis::preventOutOfRange()
{
    setMin((min() < lockMin) ? lockMin : min());
    setMax((max() > lockMax) ? lockMax : max());
}
```

```
#pragma once
#include <QValueAxis>

class CustomValueAxis : public QValueAxis
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    int lockMin;
    int lockMax;

    CustomValueAxis();
    CustomValueAxis(int min, int max);

private slots:
    void preventOutOfRange();
};
```

Then connect a signal to the slot. I did it for QValueAxis but it should be the same for categoryAxis.